# How to make a div be to the right of selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two panels, left and right. Once a user hovers the mouse over any elements of the right panel, a new div (called box) should be visible to the right of the hovered element.

I could design it, but the problem is as the width is fixed the position of the popup panel changes based on size of the screen. It does not work properly on JSFiddle so I did not put it there, however, the complete code is provided that works fine in any browser.

- Please notice both panels are in a 'container'.
- Even if the screen size get changed the red box should stay on the right panel. (where is shown in screen shots)
- red box wont be shown for mobile devices due to their small screen.

**Positions**

```
Left Panel Right Panel
Element1  |box1
Element2  |box2
```

The box elements overlap the right panel.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
          <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7" style="background-color: blue;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right: 0;">
                            <div class="myTarget" style="background-color: white;">
                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                                                <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                <div id="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs"
                                    style="display: none; z-index: 1000; background-color: red; border-color: blue;">
                                    <p>This is the third panel of element 1 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="myTarget" style="background-color: white;">
                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                                                <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                <div id="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs"
                                    style="display: none; z-index: 1000; background-color: red; border-color: blue;">
                                    <p>This is the third panel of element 2 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightPanel" class="col-md-4" style="background-color:green;padding-left: 0">
                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                $(".myTarget").hover(function() {
            var temp= $(this).children("#box");
            var tempLeft = $('#rightPanel').offset().left;
            temp.css({
                display : "block",
                position : "absolute",
                left : tempLeft + "px",
                top : 0 + "px",
            });
        }, function() {
            $(this).children("#box").hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose this is what Daniel wants

***None* of the elements is hovered**

[image]

***Element 1 is hovered*, so the *red box of element* one will be shown on its right.**

[image]

***Element 2 is hovered*, so the *red box of element two* will be shown on its right.**

[image]

Comment: You can just position it via Javascript at the moment you make it visible and then reposition it anytime it's visible when the window size changes (causing a relayout).  Or, you can use CSS styling to position it relative to other elements.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know buddy but not sure how

Comment: Then ask a more specific question about what exactly you want help with.  Your question is far too nebulous as there are lots of different approaches depending upon exactly what you're trying to do and exactly how you want it positioned, when you want it positioned, whether it overlaps with other things, etc.  I'd suggest you ask a more specific question and you're more likely to get a detailed answer.  The "buddy" reference in your comment didn't come across very well.  I was trying to help you.  If you'd rather I not try to help, I can happily spend time on other questions and ignore yours.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for misunderstanding, anyways I updated the question if it is still unclear please let me know to reword it

Comment: Are you trying to do a static design (just HTML and CSS)?  Or are you adding the element with Javascript and you want to position it with Javascript?  Also, does it overlap with other objects (e.g. need to be positioned absolutely) or can it be part of the normal page layout?  And, please tell us exactly which element in your HTML you are trying to position relative to which other element.  You've included HTML, but not told us which items in it you're asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 the boxes would overlap the right panel. I do not care about js and static option, all I want is to make sure it work in every screen size. (except cell phones)

Comment: I cannot guess, what is the reason for negative vote?

Comment: Screenshots are added to the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have two elements with the same ID. This is bad, so I've changed them to classes. I've removed the nasty inline styles and used some proper CSS declaration. I've also changed your boxes to be spans. You'll see why in a moment.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj9z21q9/) for if the below Code Snippet doesn't work.

From what I understand, you want your `box` to be positioned relative to your `p` tags. Based upon this I suggest changing your `box` element to a `span` and then using jQuery `clone()` function like so:

```js
$('.myTarget').on('mouseover', 'p', function () {
    $(this).parent().children('.box').clone().appendTo($(this));    
});
$('.myTarget').on('mouseout', 'p', function () {
    $(this).children('.box').remove(); 
});
```

```css
.col-md-7 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.col-md-12 {
    padding-right: 0;
}
#rightPanel {
    background-color:green;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.myTarget {
    background-color: white;
}
.box {
    display:none;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
    border-color:blue;
}

.myTarget p {
    position:relative;
}
.myTarget p .box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="myTarget">
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <div class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs">
                            <p>This is the third panel of element 1 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myTarget">
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <span class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs">
                            <p>This is the third panel of element 2 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightPanel" class="col-md-4">
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the CSS positioning of `.myTarget p .box` to position it as you see fit.

#### EDIT 1

Now you've clarified what you need with your image, I've updated the code. Comment should explain it, and here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj9z21q9/1/) in case the snippet doesn't work:

```js
// Loop through each box and set the width to the same as #rightPanel
$('.box').each(function() {
   var newWidth = $('#rightPanel').outerWidth();
   $(this).outerWidth(newWidth); 
});
```

```css
.col-md-7 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.col-md-12 {
    padding-right: 0;
}
#rightPanel {
    background-color:green;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.myTarget {
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
}
.box {
    display:none;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
    border-color:blue;
  
    /* Position the box to the top right of .myTarger */
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.myTarget:hover .box { /* Show the box on hover */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="myTarget">
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 1 of panel left</p>
                        <div class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs">
                            <p>This is the third panel of element 1 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myTarget">
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                        <span class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs">
                            <p>This is the third panel of element 2 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightPanel" class="col-md-4">
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
            <p>This is panel right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, the problem is the box is moving with the coordinates of the mouse, I just need the position of the box to be fixed and in size of the element of left panel that is hovered by user. The reason is if you move the mouse on the element it causes the red box to blink, as its position changes.

Comment: I'm assuming that Daniel Newtown and @Jack are the same person here? I have updated the answer based upon the new information.

Comment: @JamieBarker :D no point to be one, I have similar issue so I put the bounty for the question.

Comment: @JamieBarker Thanks for the answer, I will give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You want to position the box next to right and vertical align with myTarget div?
Add one more line in your script and see.

```
$(".myTarget").hover(function() {
   var box_top = $(this).position().top;
   var temp= $(this).children("#box");
   var tempLeft = $('#rightPanel').offset().left;
   temp.css({
      display : "block",
      position : "absolute",
      left : tempLeft + "px",
      top : box_top + "px",
   });
}, function() {
  $(this).children("#box").hide();
});
```

**Element 1 mouseover**

[image]

**Element 2 mouseover**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can I make the red box closer to the left panel? As demonstrated in the "positions" section of question boxes should be where right panel is.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a copy of your code and changed it.
Move all css of the elements and into a css file!!!!
Change the Box from id to class.
Set the leftPanels position to relative.
Set the box css: position:absolute; display:none;z-index:1000;left:100%;
Simple show the "box" within the current "myTarget" on mouseover.
Set the with to the with of the "rightPanel" if you want!

Heres the code:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-7" style="background-color: blue;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right: 0;">
                                        <div class="myTarget" style="background-color: white;position: relative;">
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <p>This is element 1 of panel left </p>
                                            <div class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs"
                                                 style="position: absolute;top:0px; left:100%; display: none; z-index: 1000; background-color: red; border-color: blue;">
                                                <p>This is the third panel of element 1 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="myTarget" style="background-color: white; position: relative;">
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <p>This is element 2 of panel left</p>
                                            <div class="box" class="col-md-8 hidden-xs"
                                                 style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:100%;  display: none; z-index: 1000; background-color: red; border-color: blue;">
                                                <p>This is the third panel of element 2 that need to be re-positioned.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="rightPanel" class="col-md-4" style="background-color:green;padding-left: 0">
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                                <p>This is panel right</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        $(function(){//start of load
                            //This only works if box is inside leftPanel, and leftPanel have position absolute or relative!
                            //Set box "position:absolute;display:none;z-index:9999;top:0" with css
                            $(".myTarget").hover(function() {
                               //CHANGE "box" id to class!!
                               var box = $(this).children(".box")
                               box.show();
                               //If you want dynamic resize of with:
                               box.css("width", $("#rightPanel").outerWidth());
                            }, function() {
                              $(".box").hide();//hide all "box" class elements
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the mouse's position and use that information to place the second div.

---

```
    getMousePosition: function(){ 
        var xOffset = event.pageX;
        var yOffset = event.pageY;
        //////////////console.log("xOffset: " + xOffset);
        //////////////console.log("yOffset: " + yOffset);
    }, //. getMousePosition
```

---

Or you could place the divs in the correct position at the outset and apply "display:none" to the second div. Then simply turn it on "display:block;" when it's required. If needed fill div2 with ajax inserted content when it's called up.

Or you could get the position of the upper left corner of div 1 and use that information to place div 2 into the correct location with a javascript adjustment.

Many ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Using the position of mouse does not work because the position of the box is based on element not mouse, the mouse pointer can be in any coordinate within the selected element.

Comment: I offered three options, I'm well aware that the mouse position is relative, not exact to the div's position. But it might help him think about his solution. I use mouse position often for tool tips where position does not need to be exact.  Don't think I deserved a thumbs down for offering alternatives. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You question is weird! You talk about a selection (There's nothing selected, hover is not the same as select!), and some kind of length? (Do you mean width?)

Anyway, you can position anything as you like with js:
Inside your hover function you can find all postion of the current ".myTarget", change `this` with "#rightPanel" and you have all positions of the rightPanel:

```
var Top = $(this).offset().top;
var Left = $(this).offset().left;
var Width = $(this).outerHeight();
var Height = $(this).outerHeight();
var Bottom = Top + Height;
var Right = Left + Width;
```

Note: if you want it to change when resizing the window, you need to tab into the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    //do stufff
})
```

Comment: @DanielNewtown With the "Top" and "Right" I just give you, then just write this in your hover function: 
$("#rightPanel").css({top: Top, left: Right });

Comment: whats your idea about Jamies' answer?

Comment: Jamies start by having the "hover" event moved from the "leftPanel" to the "p" tag of the leftPanels, so if thats what you want, its find. This means that the "box" will be left of the "p" tags, not the "leftPanel"! But then he create a clone of the "box", on every mouse over and put it into the "p" tag, which he destroy on mouseout. I whould do this different! It also seems wired! He's correct in the fact that you can't have the same id on both "box" element! Why are they inside the leftPanels, even though you want them positioned outside. (It's not that you cant do that, but why?)